# How to read value from UPDATE .. OUTPUT in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Unfortunately I couldn't found issues to push values which I receive after update query.
I have this SQL command:

```
@"if exists (select Id from Documents where Id=3) 
                begin 
                    update Documents set Modified='Jackson',ModifiedDate=(getdate()),Start= getdate(),Finish=(select dateadd(year,Termen,getdate()) from DocumentTypes where [Key]='ITO')
                    output deleted.FilePath as OldFile, inserted.FilePath as NewFile
                    where Id=3
                end"
```

And I tried to access it as

```
string old = cmd.Parameters["OldFile"].value;
```

but it is not working and I need another solution.

If is possible to make it withoute

```
SqlParameter.Direction property
```

Comment: You need to shown more and explain more to make your question understandable.

Comment: Are you looking for [SqlParameter.Direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.direction(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: (Make sure to post code that at compiles, unless the compiler errors *are* the problem. In the post, `.values` is trivially incorrect; correct the post as necessary to avoid such possibly irrelevant tangents.)

Comment: @Reniuz But how to *"bind"* such an OUTPUT value?

Comment: You should show more of your code, but `OUTPUT` just creates a result set - it should look similar to how you write code that deals with a `SELECT` query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Almost enough for an answer ..

Comment: 1. Create parameter variable. 2. Set direction to output. 3. Execute stored procedure/reader(reader must be closed before accessing parameter). 4. Get parameter value. If there are more questions please show what you already done and its not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You asked if it is possible to make it without using the 'SqlParameter.Direction' property, and I think the answer is "no, it isn't". Anyway, this is how you can do what you asked using that property. First you should make a stored procedure of your SQL commands in SQL Management Studio (inline SQL commands in your code aren't secure) by doing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFilePaths
@OldFile nvarchar(1000) output,
@NewFile nvarchar(1000) output
AS

if exists (select Id from Documents where Id=3) 
            begin 
                update Documents set Modified='Jackson',ModifiedDate=(getdate()),Start= getdate(),Finish=(select dateadd(year,Termen,getdate()) from DocumentTypes where [Key]='ITO')
                where Id=3
                set @OldFile = deleted.FilePath
                set @NewFile = inserted.FilePath
            end
```

Then in your ADO.net framework solution, you should have something like this:

```
        public static void GetPaths()
    {
        //substitute DB.GetSqlConnection() for your way of getting your connection
        using (SqlConnection conn = DB.GetSqlConnection())
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"GetFilePaths"
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //Declare the output parameters you're gonna use in your stored procedure
                SqlParameter oldFile_param = new SqlParameter("OldFile", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000);
                oldFile_param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                SqlParameter newFile_param= new SqlParameter("NewFile", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000);
                newFile_param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(oldFile_param);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(newFile_param);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                object oldFile = oldFile_param.Value;
                object newFile = newFile_param.Value;

            }
        }
    }
```

The filepaths you desired will be in 'object oldFile' and 'object newFile' .